Github actions with LFS: git fetch -all finds different amount of files when called from github actions
There is a diffrence in the amount of files found by fetch when called from workflow and from local in the same repo/branch.
How can it be that git lfs fetch --all finds around 200 when called from the Github Action workflow. Whe I run it locally, it returns around 700.
How could it have got to this state?
Can I get to a clean state somehow?
